# How to add new file type filter in Save as dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to add a new file type in the `File -> Save As file` type filter in Microsoft Visual Studio code editor?

Like `Save as type: Plain Text (*.txt,*.gitignore).`

I tried to add it in the "file association" settings section, but it is not showing up in the `Save as filter.`